# How to modify Yii2 gridview

Tags: php, yii2

I don't able to figure out how to modify `\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\grid\GridView.php` to make the field `name` of Country model regarded in official tutorial about gii to be a link to the country view.

I tried with `renderTableRow()` but I could not able to find where could I make such hypo code:

```
if (ThisFieldModel == name) makeItsTextAsLink(text, url)



public function renderTableRow($model, $key, $index)
    {           
        $cells = [];
        /* @var $column Column */
        foreach ($this->columns as $column) {
            $cells[] = $column->renderDataCell($model, $key, $index);
        }
        if ($this->rowOptions instanceof Closure) {
            $options = call_user_func($this->rowOptions, $model, $key, $index, $this);
        } else {
            $options = $this->rowOptions;
        }
        $options['data-key'] = is_array($key) ? json_encode($key) : (string) $key;

        return Html::tag('tr', implode('', $cells), $options);
    }
```

Another question: Where could I able to copy `\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\grid\GridView.php` to modify it and use it without affecting the core of yii.

Comment: Why are you messing about in core files? There's lots and lots of stuff you can do with simply calling `$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView')` and modifying the column in there.

Comment: @Mave Where could I find this in the [class reference](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/index.html)

Comment: Googling Yii GridView gives you this: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView

Comment: I'm talking here about Yii2. @Mave

Comment: Whoops, my bad. Very sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the solution, it is possible to customize column from the widgets call, so we will not need any modification in the widget's core code or creating new widget as follows:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'code',
            [ 'attribute' => 'name', 'format' => 'raw', 'value' => function($data){return "<a href=\"?r=country/view&id={$data->code}\">{$data->name}</a>";}],
            'population',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

The base of solution depends on the `columns` property of the widget, here I replaced the `name` after `code` in the columns list with

```
[ 'attribute' => 'name', 'format' => 'raw', 'value' => function($data){return "<a href=\"?r=country/view&id={$data->code}\">{$data->name}</a>";}],
```

Notice the callback function that formats the value of the field.